# Can deleting an answer to a question result in tumbleweed being awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tumbleweed-badge

I deleted an answer to one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580163/override-disable-dependency-analysis-in-visual-studio-setup-project) after discovering that the answer I proposed didn't work.  My next update reported that I'd been awarded the tumbleweed badge, so I assume that was the question that earned it for me.

Giving the badge for a question that did have an answer strikes me as a bit odd though, and I'm wondering it it's a bug.

Comment: `Possible-bug`is superfluous if you ask me. Let the team decide that.

Comment: If anything I'd argue the the other way.  I'm not sure if this is a bug, or by design; only the team knows that.  I'd only have used possible-bug except that I couldn't post without on the the other tags as well.

Comment: That's the point, Dan. You had to use `discussion` because you have to choose one of the main tags. The main tag for a (possible) bug is `bug`. `possible` is superfluous. Don't mess with the categories ;)

Comment: If possible bug is totally redundant, why hasn't it been deleted then?

Comment: @Dan: That's a pretty good question. I do my very best ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that the Tumbleweed badge is indeed awarded for questions where the only answer is deleted.

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/111639/trendnet-te100-mp1u-print-server-wont-connect-to-my-canon-s750) over on Super User a couple of weeks ago and a day or so later thought that I'd found the answer so I posted my own answer and then accepted it. Things change (as they do) and the problem came back so I unaccepted my answer and deleted it as the information now needed to be in the question.

The question now had no answers and only 31 views which is not unreasonable given I thought I'd solved the problem.

Within seconds I got the Tumbleweed badge. :(

<sup>The annoying thing is I've now remembered what I did the first time and solved the problem.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It's probable that by the time the check cleared, your bill at the end of the dinner for the badge was so low it counted as Tumbleweed status and you were able to continue eating your meal in the alleyway behind the restaurant.

Comment: metaphor fail..