# A potential tumbleweed is self-fueling until it becomes a tumbleweed

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043997/soapui-api-wsdlproject-unable-to-load-a-composite-project) on SO and it has been 24 hrs with only 8 views and 0 votes.
Currently it looks like a potential **tumbleweed**.

The problem is that it is now very unlikely that anyone will find this question and accidentally answer it -- meaning it will become a tumbleweed in around 6 days.

Is there anyway to prevent that? (I really prefer an answer to a badge :))

Comment: Linking to the question here will certainly attract attention. I see both myself and Gamecat had the same idea...

Comment: And even though your question is not that old yet, you might still try some of the classic strategies listed here: [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Thanks all (and thanks for the up-vote  on the SO question :))

Comment: no one wants that cursed badge :P

Comment: what about the gotta catch them all badge hunters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can edit the question to bump it back to the front page.

You can also put a bounty on it which puts it on display for 7 days.

And you could provide a link to the question in your meta question, which also increases the traffic to the post.

Comment: Regarding *"And you could provide a link to the question in your meta question, which also increases the traffic to the post"*, I believe he's asking about tumbleweed questions in general. Not just this particular tumbleweed question.

Answer (score 3):

Posting link to the question here usually cause many people to look at the question - if not answer or comment, the view count will greatly increase so you'll most likely dodge the badge.

As with any question, adding more details and worst case starting a bounty usually help getting answers.